# how to use rapids in colab easily

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-colaboratory, rapids, cudf

When i use rapids (cudf) in colaboratory, I execute commands as follows.But this commands usually takes about 20 minutes,so I have to wait everytime to use cudf.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rY7Ln6rEE1pOlfSHCYOVaqt8OvDO35J0#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true

Does anyone know how to easily use cudf with colab without this command?

Comment: Try SageMaker Studio Lab instead for a persistent setup (it also supports the current version of RAPIDS libraries). https://rapids.ai/start.html

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is no faster way. While it's technically possible to create an image with the various libraries/dependencies installed, it's probably not a priority for Google. For faster alternative, there are [paid GPU-cloud instances](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-cloud-computing/google-cloud-platform/).